# How to get the right ascension of the Moon?

Tags: the-moon, solar-system, astrophysics, right-ascension

Is there any approximate way to calculate the right ascension of the Moon? I already got declination but still, need the right ascension to calculate the final position of the moon. Thanks for all your answers!

Comment: Can you explain how or where you found how to calculate the declination?  Also, how accurate or appropriate do you want the Right Ascension?

Comment: The astronomical almanac has a low precision moon position, accurate to .5 deg from 1900-2100.  Example implementation here: https://www.celestialprogramming.com/lowprecisionmoonposition.html

Comment: A more accurate method is to use VSOP 87: https://github.com/gmiller123456/vsop87-multilang.  Highest precision can be obtained from using JPL's Development Ephemeris.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not opposed to a bit of Python, you can easily compute this with astropy.

```
import astropy.time
import astropy.coordinates

moon = astropy.coordinates.get_moon(astropy.time.Time.now())
print(moon.ra)
```

Which outputs

```
<Longitude 115.085153 deg>
```